# How can I force the keyboard to appear?

Tags: java, android, keyboard

When the user clicks on an editText the keyboard is brought up for the user to type. Can I make the keyboard to appear when a user clicks on a button instead of the editText? Can the numpad appear instead of the normal keyboard?

Comment: When user clicks on button? When will the keyboard focus? For your second question, if you do android:inputType="number" what you'll get will be numpad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can i make the keyboard to appear when a user clicks on a button
>   instead of the editText?

Yes, you need to set the focus and pop up the keyboard using `InputMethodManager`

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Focus the field.
            editText.requestFocus();
            // Show soft keyboard for the user to enter the value.
            InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            im.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
    });
```

> Can the numpad appear instead of the normal keyboard?

Yes, using input type

Either in the xml tag of `edittext`

```
 <EditText...
     android:inputType="number"/>
```

or in java

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void toggleKeyboard(Context context) {
    try {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("On show keyboard error: %s", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```